# How to return the String from String Array that contains a particular Substring in C#?

Tags: c#, string, loops, arraylist, substring

I am taking string array of arguments of command line and checking if there is any argument which contains a ".xml" substring

```
string[] args = this.Command.GetCommandLineArgs();
string strXMLFileName = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
{
    if (args[i].Contains(".xml"))
    {
        strXMLFileName = args[i];
    }
}
```

I searched a bit in List<string> methods, but couldn't find anything that could simplify the process

*I am assuming there is only 1 argument with ".xml" substring*

**Is there any built-in C# method with which I can do this without manually iterating through the string array**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

```
var strXMLFileName = args.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(".xml"));
```

Will yield `null` is there is no such argument.

---

NB: For the search string `".xml"`, `EndsWith` is usually more appropriate than `Contains`.

Comment: what if file name is `pra.xml.txt`? your query will store it sas strXMLFileName. which is not expected right?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar: That's why I added my "NB" comment. OP explicitly wrote *"contains a ".xml" substring"*, so I did not dare change that on my own. I was about to add a comment about `SingleOrDefault`  being an alternative that throws an exception, but you beat me to it. :-)

Comment: The "first or default" returns 'null' if no value found. How can I code it to make string.Empty as return value. I know I check if null and assign accordingly, but is there an overload of FirstOrDefault where I can specify the default value?

Comment: I found it. The ?? operator helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-5.0), so that you will get an exception if there are multiple `.xml` files are available in the list. I used [`EndsWith()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-5.0) instead of `Contains()`, so that condition will check file ends with `.xml` or not.

```
var strXMLFileName = args.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith(".xml")) ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that string with `.xml` is in array:

```cs
var arr = new string[]
{
    "file1.txt",
    "file2.xml",
    "file3.xml",
};

var strXMLFileName = arr.First(x => x.EndsWith(".xml"));

System.Console.WriteLine(strXMLFileName);
```

If you are not sure:

```cs
var arr = new string[]
{
    "file1.txt",
    "file2.xml",
    "file3.xml",
};

var strXMLFileName = arr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith(".xml"));

System.Console.WriteLine(strXMLFileName);
```

Comment: You do realize that [Enumerable.First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-5.0) is in the `System.Linq` namespace and, thus, considered a part of LINQ?

Comment: This code is also using LINQ. Don't see an added advantage as such.

Comment: Yes, my bad, sorry